# Adding personalized links in edits

Tags: discussion, badges, review, suggested-edits

Recently, while reviewing suggested [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits), I noticed that the answer editor added a link to some other answer (which is fine) but the link was not in *generic** format but in *personalized** format.

Thanks to that change, the post editor may easily gain **Announcer**, **Booster**, or **Publicist** badges (especially on frequently view posts). Personally I consider adding *personalized** links in edits to be cheating i.e. trying to gain some rewards (badges) with no additional effort, say, of answering the question.

Is there any recommended approach to that kind of edits? Shall we reject the edit or improve it by replacing personalized link with the generic ones?

Do you share my opinion or you consider that behaviour acceptable?

---

> By ***generic*** URLs I understand URL format as follows:
>
> ```
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/_question_id_/_question-friendly-url_/_anser_id_#_anser_id_
> ```
>
> By ***personalized*** URL I understand URL format as follows:
>
> ```
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/_answer_id_/_profile_id_
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Announcer, Booster and Publicist badges are only awarded for incoming links from non-SE sites.

As such, it doesn't matter if the links in answers are personalized; clicking on those links *does not count* towards those badges.

From the [FAQ on badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> Only clicks from *outside* the Stack Exchange network count towards the badge.

The `share` link below a post always includes the personalized URL and is currently the easiest way to obtain a link to a specific answer. As a result, most people obtain a URL for an answer using that link and it is *normal* that you see them being used in posts.

There is no need to reject such edits, nor is there any need to remove the personalized id. Do not reject or improve such edits on the grounds of such links alone.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer. I haven't seen the mentioned post before and the badges page (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges) does not specify that condition.

Comment: @Tom: It is also mentioned in the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) announcing the badges.